# Inno Setup Installer has squished window on XP?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating installers to run on Windows Embedded Standard (which is basically Windows XP Embedded).  However, on these XP devices, the installer displays with a horizontally squished window.

This is what an installer built with Inno Setup 4 looks like:
[image: Inno Setup 4 squished window]

And this is what an installer built with Inno Setup 5 installer looks like:
[image: Inno Setup 5 squished window]

Inno Setup is the only program I've ever had this sort of trouble with.  Any ideas on how I can get the installer window to show up so that the text is visible?  I don't care if it's maximized or hardcoded or whatever -- I just need the window to show up with a visible size.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: What is "Inno Setup 5"? Are you using the latest version 5.5.9?

Comment: Try to add this to the `[Code]` section: `procedure InitializeWizard(); begin Log(Format('X=%d Y=%d', [ScaleX(10), ScaleY(10)])); end;` What output would it produce in the log?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl, thanks so much for the helpful reply!

The log file shows:

2017-03-10 05:13:01.875   X=0 Y=10

I have attached the full log here:  http://pastebin.com/6G6TkJcp

Comment: I will also note that I've tried to change the screen resolution, and confirmed that this window scaling issue happens at different sizes.  My monitor's DPI setting is currently at 96 dpi.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying the version number.  Yes, this is using Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.9.  I'm just using the basic example installer files -- this doesn't have any of my custom code in it yet.

Comment: Did you try using Unicode version of Inno Setup? + What does this produce? `Log(Integer(FontExists('Microsoft Sans Serif')))` and `Log(Integer(FontExists('MS Sans Serif')))`?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl, I just tried the Unicode version of Inno Setup, and that worked beautifully!  Thank you VERY much!  

I logged the output of that script with both the Unicode version as well as the regular version, and both output "1" to the log for both fonts.  

In Unicode, it outputs "X=10, Y=10", and in the regular, it still outputs "X=0, Y=10".  

Thank you VERY much for the help!  This will work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tested yourself, Unicode version of Inno Setup works correctly.

It is built using a newer version of Delphi IDE, what likely fixes some rare bug, that occurs with your machines.

And you should use Unicode version anyway!